# Button redirect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me why this is not working:

```
<button class="btn danger" id="delete" onclick="return $(location).attr('href','http://yahoo.com');">Delete</button>
```

I have this placed in a form just beside the submit button. When it's clicked, it's like I clicked the submit button.

Comment: Needs to be `onclick` rather than `onlick`.

Comment: and what's wrong with just saying `window.location = 'http:// ... /` ?

Comment: @jakeclarkson I edited the post. The problem isn't caused by the typo.

Comment: @oaziz thought it might have been a typo :) i'd go with Alnitak and just use `window.location = '...'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to make the button load that URL, the correct way to do it is:

```
<button class="btn danger" id="delete" onclick="document.location.href = 'http://yahoo.com'">
```

I don't think wrapping it in jQuery helps much here since location isn't a DOM object.

Comment: This is not working: <button class="btn danger" id="delete" onclick="document.location.href = 'http://yahoo.com'">Delete</button>

Comment: It works if I put it in an html document on it's own, so either you've mistyped it, or there's something else in your page interfering with it. Do you have any other javascripts or stylesheets that might stop it from working? Can you post a link to the page so we can see it in context?

Answer (score 0):

Use the window.location property. See comment below.

Comment: This is assuming you are trying to use jquery. Otherwise, using onclick="window.location = 'http://www.yahoo.com'"